# Reversing a number in C++ using Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

When i write this code, It does the job but also prints some random stuff.

If my input is 32, it prints 23 followed a line of random numbers
. example:

```
23 983748572819937482
```

I wanna know what these random numbers are and why they are being printed

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int reverse(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        cout << " ";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        int lastdigit = n % 10;
        int firstdigit = n / 10;
        cout << lastdigit << reverse(firstdigit);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    reverse(n);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should always compile with warnings enabled and as a beginner always have treat warnings as errors.

If you do that you would see that `reverse` doesn't return a value on all paths. As such when you do `cout << reverse (firstdigit);` you try to print what `reverse` returns and that is Undefined Behavior.

If you implement the function like this (by printing inside it) your function doesn't need to return a value. So this will work:

```
void reverse(int n) {
    if (n==0){
        cout << " ";
    }
    else {
    
     int lastdigit = n%10;
     int firstdigit = n/10;
     cout << lastdigit;

     reverse (firstdigit);
   }
}
```

However I don't think that is the intent of the exercise. I think your function should return the reversed number, not print it. So think about how you would modify the function to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you so much . I aspire to help other newbie programmers just like how you did, when I get good at programming. Thanks again, have a great day :)

Answer (score 2):

As you're not capturing the return value, this function should be void, and can be used like this:

```
void reverse(int n) {
    if (n==0){
        cout << n
        return;
    }
    else {

        int lastdigit = n%10;
        int firstdigit = n/10;
        cout << lastdigit;
        if(firstdigit != 0) 
            reverse (firstdigit);
    }
}
```

Also the notation of "firstdigit" implies that its only the first digit, though its actually the rest of the number. I.E: `545/10 = 54`

Comment: yeah.. I should have written "firstpart" instead of "firstdigit". Thanks for pointing it out and thank you for your response. Have a nice day :)))

Answer (score 0):

> I wanna know what these random numbers are and why they are being
> printed.

The weird numbers come from the second call to `reverse`: that call doesn't return anything, but `cout << reverse(firstdigit)` is still executed, leading to undefined consequences.

You can see it better if you annotate the code and print out whenever you enter and exit the `reverse` function:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/cq63och5e)

```cpp
#include <cstdint>  // intptr_t
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int reverse(int n) {
    std::cout << "\nCalling reverse(" << n << ") >>>\n";
    if (n == 0) {
        cout << " ";
        std::cout << "\n<<< Returning " << 0 << " from reverse(" << n << ")\n";
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        int lastdigit = n % 10;
        int firstdigit = n / 10;
        cout << lastdigit << reverse(firstdigit);
        std::cout << "\n<<< UB: callers might see a return value of " 
            << reinterpret_cast<std::intptr_t>(&cout) << " from reverse(" << n << ")\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    reverse(n);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   Calling reverse(32) >>>
//   2
//   Calling reverse(3) >>>
//   3
//   Calling reverse(0) >>>
//    
//   <<< Returning 0 from reverse(0)
//   0
//   <<< UB: callers might see a return value of 4210816 from reverse(3)
//   4210816
//   <<< UB: callers might see a return value of 4210816 from reverse(32)
```

The traces show:

- `reverse(32)`is called. `cout << lastdigit` prints `2` and then we call `reverse(lastdigit)`.
- `reverse(3)` is called. `cout << lastdigit` prints `3` and then we call `reverse(lastdigit)`.
- `reverse(0)` is called. `cout << " "` prints  , and `0` is returned.
- Now we are back to the `reverse(3)` call; we had printed out `3`, and we print the int value returned from `reverse(firstdigit)`, which is a `0`. And **we return from this call to `reverse` without a `return` statement**. gcc warns us about this with `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`.
- Finally, we are back to the `reverse(32)` call; we had printed out `2`, and we print the int value returned from `reverse(firstdigit)`. **Using a return value from a function declared to return a value and that didn't explicitly return it is undefined behaviour.**

The caller to `reverse(3)` is getting whatever it is where the return value should be (e.g. `EAX` register). In this case, it happens to be the result of the last expression evaluated in the `reverse(3)` call, the value returned by `operator<<`, `std::cout&`.

---

One possible fix: change the `reverse` function so that it doesn't return anything and just print the numbers.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/9zsrbcTG3)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout

void reverse(int n) {
    if (n <= 9) {
        std::cout << n;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << n%10;
        reverse(n/10);
    }
}

int main() {
    for (int n : { 0, 5, 15, 125 })
    {
        reverse(n);
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I sure did change the code and now it works. Thank you for your response. Have a blissful day :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful!